# Windows 10: Missing boot.wim?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade

I am trying to get Windows 10 to install on my brand-new 8.1 laptop. As some background, when I first started up the laptop, I was shown the GWX dialog asking if I wanted to register for Windows 10. After that, the GWX icon would **not** appear in the system tray until I installed every possible update, including optional updates, [ran the command line script to validate GWX](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/i-want-to-reserve-my-free-copy-of-windows-10-but-i/848b5cce-958b-49ae-a132-a999a883265b?auth=1), and rebooted my computer several times.

Now the GWX icon shows up and my system has downloaded 6.5 gigabytes of files into the hidden download folder at `$Windows.~BT` . The size of the folder has not changed for several hours and I see no indication that Windows 10 is still downloading.

If I run the setup.exe in that directory, I get an error that boot.wim is missing. Is that normal or did something go wrong? What can I do now?

- Windows 8.1
- Every possible Windows update installed
- Exceeds system requirements
- GWX icon shows
- GWX app has confirmation

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/error-code-0x80070002/f79d6bc5-6a12-4174-bb6f-820439476907 I asked this question on the Microsoft forum as I am having the same issue. There, MAMohammed AliAli (Microsoft Support Engineer) replied on July 30, 2015 with: > Hi,
> > Thank you for posting your query in Microsoft Community.
> > We are working on this issue, we will get back with you very soon.
> > Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the Media Creation Tool (32 or 64-bit) to download Windows 10 manually and create an ISO or DVD or USB -

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

If you don't want to create installation media for future use (on the same or different system), just select **Upgrade this PC now** -

[image: Windows 10 Media Creation Tool]

You can read more about the Tool on this page -

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install

Comment: I found out you don't even need to create a separate media (good, because I can't boot my laptop from USB for some reason - I tinkered with the UEFI but no luck). You can just open the Media Creation Tool on the system you want to upgrade and tell it that you want to upgrade that system instead of creating the media

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer to include that information?

Comment: I have done as you requested, hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome, I hope that helps others as well.